# How do I login to my repo using gitbash?

Tags: github

I have added my self to the git bash program but can't find on google how to login?

```
$ git config --global user.name "myname"
$ git config --global user.email myemail@example.com
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The user.name and user.email have nothing to do with login credentials.
They are metadata attached to your commits.

To "login", you need to add a remote url which will use your credentials, either https or ssh one.

```
git remote add origin https://UserName:password@github.com/UserName/yourRepo.git
                                 ^
                                 |
                              (credentials)
```

Or ssh:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com/UserName/yourRepo.git
```

(which would means that you have in `HOME/.ssh` your `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` private and public key, with the public key registered in your GitHub account: see "[Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-all)")

---

See more at "[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)".

As noted by [paddymac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6140412/paddymac) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838207/how-do-i-login-to-my-repo-using-gitbash/20838581?noredirect=1#comment106492982_20838581), if `origin` already exists, use [`git remote set-url origin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem) instead of `git remote add origin`

Comment: To add on to this. If you have already cloned your repo and you get the error "Remote origin already exists", then use 'git set-url' as opposed to 'git add'